# Session in JSON Symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have simple action

```
 public function addAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    $session = $request->getSession();
    if(!$session->has('basket'))
        $session->set('basket', array());
    $basket = $session->get('basket');
    $basket[$id] = array('id' => $id, 'count' => $request->query->get('count'));
}
```

I want to add my data to json array, because, i think, it is a good practice. Please, help me convert my array in json

P.S
 My array look now

```
 [
   5 => [
      id => 5, 
      count => 8
   ],
   8 => [
      id => 8, 
      count => 32
   ]
]
```

What i want:

```
"order": [
 {
  "id": 34,
  "count": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 56,
  "count": "8
 }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the session object is already going to do serialization for you.

Comment: @ Peter Bailey i refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a straight-forward change to me

Instead of

```
$basket[$id] = array('id' => $id, 'count' => $request->query->get('count'));
```

use

```
$basket['order'][] = array('id' => $id, 'count' => $request->query->get('count'));
```